# How to use to diff to C++ source files and ignore the line space and comments

Tags: linux

I have to C++ source files and I want to see the difference between the two files. But I don't want to see the diff between the comments.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have multi-line comments that aren't starting with `*` in every line? If not, I could hack something together with `grep`

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use the pre-processor to remove the comments and pass this into `diff` using [*process substitution*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)...

```
diff -uwB <(g++ -E left.cpp) <(g++ -E right.cpp)
```

Of course this will pull in files that you `#include` and expand your `#define` macros, too. If they haven't changed, this should be quite readable.

The switches I have passed to [`diff`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/diff/) are:

```
-w  --ignore-all-space  Ignore all white space.
-B  --ignore-blank-lines  Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.
-u  -U NUM  --unified[=NUM]  Output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context.
```